# Controlling a robot through a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi, robotics

I'm designing a system to communicate with a robot controlled by a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino Mega. The Raspberry Pi will be runnning a web server and needs to recieve commands from an application running on the computer. I've written a simple webpage to send the commands via XMLHTTPRequest to a Bottle server on the Pi, but this is far too slow considering the speed of the motors and the precision needed to drive it.

I've had success with a Python application which opens a socket to the Pi, but this application has to run on a number of computers (Windows, OSX, and Linux), only some of which have python installed.

My main question is this: is there a way to send the commands fast enough to pilot the robot using only javascript and html?

Comment: You could look into WebSockets. They are a javascript/HTTP solution to this sort of issue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket . I don't know if the Bottle server can handle websockets but I have heard of people running Node JS on a Raspberry Pi and it can with some work.

Comment: Thank you very much! WebSockets are just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Pywebsockets allow javascript to connect with a python function back on the server and transfer data fast enough for it to be useful piloting the robot.